# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to + \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}e^{-(x-t)^2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I am really confused with x approaching $+ \infty$. How can I solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to + \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}e^{-(x-t)^2}dt$$

Comment: Try the substitution $t=x(s+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $\sqrt{\pi}$. Note that the largest contribution to the integral comes from the region around $t\approx x$. So expand $t^2/(1+t^2)$ in a Taylor series around $t\approx x$ and obtain to leading order
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}e^{-(x-t)^2}dt\approx \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x-t)^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}x^2}{1+x^2}\to\sqrt{\pi}
$$
for large $x$.